# How to view data based on user in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I want to view data from `mysql` in `codeigniter` based on user who is logged in
but I got an error "A Database Error Occurred". I think I wrote the wrong code

`t.USER = $this->session->userdata('user_id');`

Here's the code:

```
function get_rekomen() 
{
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT
   c.*,
   t.produk_id,
   t.id_transdet,
   t.kategori_id,
   t.total_qty,
   t.USER 
FROM
   transaksi_detail AS t 
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            g.id_produk,
            p.slug_produk,
            p.foto,
            p.foto_type,
            p.harga_diskon,
            p.diskon,
            p.harga_normal,
            p.judul_produk,
            g.kat_id,
            k.judul_kategori 
         FROM
            (
               SELECT
                  MAX(m.id_produk) AS id_produk,
                  m.kat_id 
               FROM
                  produk AS m 
               GROUP BY
                  m.kat_id 
            )
            AS g 
            INNER JOIN
               produk AS p 
               ON p.id_produk = g.id_produk 
            LEFT JOIN
               kategori AS k 
               ON k.id_kategori = g.kat_id 
      )
      AS c 
      ON c.kat_id = t.kategori_id 
WHERE
   t.USER = $ this -> session -> userdata('user_id');
<<// i think here's the problem

ORDER BY
   total_qty DESC limit 1")->result(); 

return $query;
}
```

and the question is what is the correct code?

Comment: please edit your answer with the complete error message, also try to echo $this->session->userdata('user_id') and see what it shows

Comment: when i try to echo "$this->session->userdata('user_id')";. i got an error A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

Filename: models/Produk_model.php

Line Number: 174

Backtrace:

Comment: You can't use PHP Code inside MYSQL Query. First you wanna test that you are getting the User ID from that syntax `$this->session->userdata('user_id');` then you use `WHERE
t.USER = ".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." ORDER` like this. Hope it will work :)

Comment: are you loading session library ? $this->load->library('session');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution, but first make sure on your controller the `$this->load->library('session');` is loaded or you can just add in on `autoload.php`.

Also you must add parameter to your model that will handle the `user_id` in session, so for example here's your model looks like:

```
function get_rekomen($user_id) { ...your query here... }
```

Then on condition using the user_id will be

```
t.USER = $user_id;
```

So on your controller, you can call your model like:

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

$this->ModelClass->get_rekomen($user_id);
```

Additional: On your login phase, if the user success from logging in, the you must set the user data on session such as this `$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $session_data);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this. You need to define $user_id first before adding them to **WHERE** statement...

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$sql = "SELECT c.*, t.produk_id, t.id_transdet, t.kategori_id, t.total_qty, t.USER 
    FROM transaksi_detail AS t 
    LEFT JOIN(SELECT g.id_produk, p.slug_produk, p.foto, p.foto_type, p.harga_diskon, p.diskon, p.harga_normal, p.judul_produk, g.kat_id, k.judul_kategori
        FROM(SELECT MAX(m.id_produk) AS id_produk, m.kat_id
            FROM produk AS m 
            GROUP BY m.kat_id)
        AS g 
        INNER JOIN produk AS p ON p.id_produk = g.id_produk 
        LEFT JOIN kategori AS k ON k.id_kategori = g.kat_id)
    AS c ON c.kat_id = t.kategori_id
    WHERE t.USER = '$user_id'
    ORDER BY total_qty DESC limit 1";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
```

Hope this can help you...